# What is the effect of calling QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() if no insertion actually takes place?

Tags: qt

I'm implementing drag/drop behavior in my model, which is derived from QAbstractItemModel.  My code (C++) for the drop event looks something like this:

```
beginInsertRows(destination_index, row, row);
destination->AcquireDroppedComponent(component);
endInsertRows();
```

The call to `AcquireDroppedComponent` can fail for a number of reasons and reject the drop, in which case no new rows will be inserted in the index stored in `destination_index`.  My question is will calling begin/endInsertRows cause problems if this happens?  My limited testing on Windows 7 so far shows no undesirable behavior, but I want to be thorough and not rely on the specific behavior of one platform.  I can check beforehand if the drop will succeed or not, but I'd like to avoid the extra code if I can.  My question also applies for the other begin/end functions like `beginRemoveRows`, `beginInsertColumns`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling these methods without doing the actions you indicate breaks their contract. How the clients of your model will cope with that is essentially undefined.

> I can check beforehand if the drop will succeed or not, but I'd like to avoid the extra code if I can.

That "extra" code is absolutely necessary.

I'd refactor your code to perform acquisition and model change separately:

```
if (destination->acquireDroppedComponent(component)) {
  beginInsertRows(destination_index, row, row);
  destination->insertDroppedComponent(component);
  endInsertRows();
}
```

The `acquireDroppedComponent` would store the data of the dropped object without modifying the model, and return `true` if it was successful and the data is usable. You then would call `insertDroppedComponent` to perform the model change.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Thanks.